# how does the bootstrap set the distance between the button like the pic

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, margin

[image: the pic is here]
the distance is marked by the red line in pic,
I do not find the setting from the css stylesheet!

Comment: Isn't this controlled via the CSS `margin` property? [CSS Margin](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```html
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">Default Button</button>

<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary">Primary Button</button>

<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-success">Success Button</button>

<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-info">Info Button</button>

<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-warning">Warning Button</button>

<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger">Danger Button</button>
```

it will working .

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is to be able to control the 'space' between these buttons.

Controlling the space around any element can be done via the CSS `margin` property.

In your case, you could create a class that defines the `margin` and use it with all your buttons. Or you could simply create an override class (in CSS) that will apply the style to all buttons.

**Method 1 : extra class**

CSS:

```
.MyButton
{
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-info MyButton" href="#">Some Text Here</a>
```

**Method 2 : Override `btn`**

CSS:

```
btn
{
  margin-right:10px;
}
```